# Using ajax javascript to load content into a div in web page

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am having a little problem using `javascript-ajax` here. In my page, I load in the content into one of the div with id `content` in an ajax manner, whenever the user clicks on links which have the class `myajaxreq`, and the contents are loaded into the div in a fade in manner. The javascript that I am using is this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#content").load($('.myajaxreq:first').attr('href'));
});


$('.myajaxreq').click(function() {
    var myhref=$(this).attr('href');
    $('#content').hide().load(myhref).fadeIn('slow');

    return false;
});
```

---

All works great on `localhost`, but when i put it online and then when we click on these links, then: First the same content which was initially there in the div is loaded in fade in manner. After a few seconds, the new content is loaded.

I think I am missing some sort of

```
if(content document is ready)
     then load in a fade in manner
         and so on..
```

Please somebody help me out here !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

call fade in after success callback... try this

```
var jContent = $('#content').hide();
jContent.load(
        myhref,
        {},
        function(){
            jContent.fadeIn('slow');
        }
    );
```

here the whole code (untested)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var jContent = $("#content").load($('.myajaxreq:first').attr('href'));

    $('.myajaxreq').click(function() {
        var myhref=$(this).attr('href');
        jContent
          .hide()
          .load(
            myhref,
            {},
            function(){
                jContent.fadeIn('slow');
            }
        );

        return false;
    }); 
});
```

Comment: +1. Besides, no need to pass an empty array as a second parameter.

Comment: I am a little new to javascript and ajax stuffs. So, plz dont mind: But whenever I paste your code into my js file, the entire css gets disoriented !! Do I need to remove the previous javascript code I have shown in the problem ??